# R generate triangle table based on a vector

Tags: r

I would like to automatically generate the following triangle table using the vector c(1,3,5,12,24,60,120) to determine the length/height of the sides

```
           [1]  [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [...]   [120]
  [1.1] 1                           
  [3.1] 1                           
  [3.2] 1   1                       
  [3.3] 1   1   1                   
  [5.1] 1                           
  [5.2] 1   1                       
  [5.3] 1   1   1                   
  [5.4] 1   1   1   1               
  [5.5] 1   1   1   1   1           
  [....]                                
  [120.120] 1   1   1   1   1   1             1
```

Comment: Hello, questions here require (a) minimal effort shown that you actually tried to solve the problem yourself and (b) a bit more clarity.   Please consider re-writing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec <- c(1,3,5,12,24,60,120)

library(plyr)
## make triangle matrices of each size
matrices <- sapply(vec, FUN = function(x) {
    as.data.frame(lower.tri(matrix(rep(NA,x^2), ncol = x), diag = TRUE))
})
out <- 1 * rbind.fill(matrices)
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
```

Note: just done for c(1,3,5) to provide example

```
## > out
##   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
## 1  1  0  0  0  0
## 2  1  0  0  0  0
## 3  1  1  0  0  0
## 4  1  1  1  0  0
## 5  1  0  0  0  0
## 6  1  1  0  0  0
## 7  1  1  1  0  0
## 8  1  1  1  1  0
## 9  1  1  1  1  1
```